# Getting stuck in a loop

Tags: python, numpy, while-loop

I have written this code, but the problem is for large number for P and SLOT, the code will be stocked in a loop and unfortunately, I do not know how to fix this problem. I would be more than thankful if someone can help me to fix this problem.
I have attached the code below for your further review.
This code is for developing a patient scheduling system based on the patient no-show.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import datetime

SLOT = 12 # Number of slots per day
PHY = 2 # Number of Physicians
P = 36 # Number of Patients
number_OB = np.zeros((PHY, 1)) # Number of overbooked for each physician

Limit_OB = np.zeros((PHY, 1))

for i in range(Limit_OB.shape[0]):
    Limit_OB[i] = 2 # Capacity of each physician is to visit maximum 2 patients in each slot

preference = [random.randint(1, 3) for i in range(P)] # patients' preference for seeing physician 1 and 2: Preference 3 means the patient has no preference for physician 1 or 2
noshowtype = [random.randint(0, 1) for i in range(P)] # 0 means the patient no-show is low and 1 means the patient no-show is high
availability = np.random.randint(2, size=(P,SLOT)) # This matrix shows the availability of each patients for each slot

# Initialization
print(preference)
print(len(preference))
print(noshowtype)
print(len(noshowtype))
print(availability)
availability.shape
totpat = np.zeros((PHY, SLOT))
tot_pat_sch = np.zeros((PHY,1))
assign = np.zeros(shape=(P, SLOT, PHY))
totpatslot = np.zeros((SLOT, 1))
noapp = np.zeros((P, 1))
put = np.zeros((P, SLOT))
unschedule = np.zeros((P,SLOT))
slotcap = [2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1]

totpatslot = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
tot_pat_sch = [0,0]
for p in range(P):
    count = 0
    if preference[p] == 3:
        for phy in range(PHY):
            for s in range(SLOT):
                tot_pat_sch[phy] = tot_pat_sch[phy] + totpat[PHY-1,s] 
        if  tot_pat_sch[0] == tot_pat_sch[1]: 
            preference[p] = random.randint(1, 2) 
    trial = 0
    if p == 4 :
        print("patient assigned ",p)
    while trial <=1:
        if noshowtype[p] == 0 & count ==0:
            for s in range(SLOT):
                if totpat[preference[p]-1, s] == 0:
                    if availability[p,s] == 1:
                        assign[p,s,preference[p]-1] = 1
                        put[p,s] = 1
                        count = 1
                        trial = 2
                        totpat[preference[p]-1,s] = totpat[preference[p]-1,s] + 1
                        totpatslot[s] = totpatslot[s] + 1
                        break;
                    print("patient scheduled ",p)
        if count == 0:
            for s in range(SLOT):
                if totpat[preference[p]-1, s] < slotcap[s]:
                    if availability[p,s] == 1:
                        assign[p,s,preference[p]-1] = 1
                        number_OB[PHY-1] = number_OB[PHY-1] + 1
                        put[p,s] = 1
                        count = 1
                        trial = 2
                        totpat[preference[p]-1,s] = totpat[preference[p]-1,s] + 1
                        totpatslot[s] = totpatslot[s] + 1
                    else:
                        unschedule[p,s] = unschedule[p,s] + 1
                        noapp[p] = 1
                        break;
        if noshowtype[p] == 1 & count == 0:
            for s in range(SLOT):
                if totpat[preference[p]-1, s] == 0:
                    if availability[p,s] == 1:
                        assign[p,s,preference[p]-1] = 1
                        put[p,s] = 1
                        count = 1
                        trial = 2
                        totpat[preference[p]-1,s] = totpat[preference[p]-1,s] + 1
                        totpatslot[s] = totpatslot[s] + 1
                        break;
                    print("patient scheduled ",p)
        if count == 0:
            for s in range(SLOT):
                if totpat[preference[p]-1, s] < slotcap[s]:
                    if availability[p,s] == 1:
                        assign[p,s,preference[p]-1] = 1
                        number_OB[PHY-1] = number_OB[PHY-1] + 1
                        put[p,s] = 1
                        count = 1
                        trial = 2
                        totpat[preference[p]-1,s] = totpat[preference[p]-1,s] + 1
                        totpatslot[s] = totpatslot[s] + 1
                    else:
                        unschedule[p,s] = unschedule[p,s] + 1
                        noapp[p] = 1
                        break;
```

Comment: What constitutes "large number for P and SLOT"?

Comment: are you sure the program does not enter infinite while? it is possible that the trail will never be updated to other than 0, have an else condition.

Comment: @ScottHunter the code will be run perfectly when P=8 and SLOT=5. But for large numbers for P and SLOT it will be stocked in the loop

Comment: @RitwickJha Thank you so much for your feedback. I am not sure if I understood correctly. Could you be more specific?

Comment: your while loop is while trail<=1:
but inside your while loop there are only if statements which update trail = 2
therefore, only when that if statement is entered will trail be updated to 2 and only then the program will exit the while loop.

you should put an else statement at the end of the while loop that breaks out of it or updates the trail to appropriate amount.

Comment: @RitwickJha the break statements must be for if noshowtype[p] == 0 & count == 0 and if noshowtype[p] == 1 & count == 0 lines?
I am not really professional in coding and sorry for any misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

I'll put it as an answer so that you can understand what I was commenting about.

```
for p in range(P):
    
    ...
    trial = 0
    while trial <=1:
        if ():
            for ():
                if ():
                    if ():
                        ...
                        trial = 2
                        break;
        if ():
            for ():
                if ():
                    if ():
                        ...
                        trial = 2
                    else:
                        ...
                        break;

        #similarly the other ifs
```

this is the structure of the code right now, which does not seem simple and is probably redundant at many points. the issue that i was asking you to check was what happens when none of the first indentation if conditions are met? the variable trial will not get updated and you will be stuck in an infinite loop inside while. the only way to break out of this while is too make the variable trial>1 or use a break.

anyways i do not see the point of the while loop here.